# Url of the picture in final PDF

Tags: graphics, context, external-files

Using ConTeXt I want to create a pdf with pictures from the internet. I don't want to include those pictures into the pdf, but I want only links to these pictures, and the pictures themselves shall be loaded when viewing the pdf. I tried to use this code:

```
%interface=en translate-file=utf-8
\starttext
\externalfigure[http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/36375617/Lucie+Jones+Lucie+PNG.png][type=png]
\stoptext
```

I used this command for the compilation:

```
texexec --pdf --tex=pdfetex --int=en file.tex
```

But in the final pdf there is only this error message:

```
name: dummy
file: Lucie+Jones+Lucie+PNG
state: unknown
```

Is it possible to have the external figures in the final pdf (using ConTeXt)?

Comment: This seems unlikely. I didn't know until today that pdf could refer to images without containing them.

Answer (score 5):

that works only with MKIV. Run it with

```
context file.tex
```

and it should work. But the image is always included in the pdf!

Comment: Thanks, this works. 
I saw pdf with linked pictures, but they probably was not created in TeX. I thaught it should be also possible in TeX to do that. Never mind, I include pictures into pdf.

Comment: I don't see this an answer to the question. The OP: “… i want only links to this pictures…”. Your solution includes the pictures. Furthermore the OP wants: “… loaded after pdf viewing”. Your solution loads them before.